# How can I keep track of a turtle's parents once they die?

Tags: netlogo

In my model parents produce offspring. The following is a procedure for the females to produce their young and here the young keep track of the identity of their parents.

```
  to reproduce
  if count mates > 0 [
    hatch 3 [
     set mother myself
     set father one-of [mates] of mother
]]
```

Tragically, their parents can die and so the `mother` and `father` variables become `nobody`. Is there a way I can keep these IDs from turning into nobody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the (very rare) cases where it is sensible to use `who`. In your case, I'd have two variables for each parent - one as you have already so you can easily make statements like `face mother` and the other stores the `who` so you can track lineages after the parents die. Your code would then look like:

```
to reproduce
  if count mates > 0 [
    hatch 3 [
     set mother myself
     set motherID [who] of mother
     set father one-of [mates] of mother
     set fatherID [who] of father
]]
```

Comment: Another possibility would be to have a `corpses` breed, and instead of `die` use `set breed corpses   hide-turtle`.